# Max nodes whose value exceeds all neighbors

Tags: algorithms, graphs, trees

A node is valid if its value is greater than all of its incident edges.

Task is to maximize the number of valid nodes.

Given $n$ values for nodes and $n-1$ values for edges, how do I assign these values (to nodes and edges) to a given input tree so the number of valid nodes is maximized?

Comment: Do you have any specific values in mind, or are they given to you arbitrarily?

Comment: Values can be anything, you may assume them to be positive integers

Comment: *Greater than each of the values of its adjacent edges*, or *Greater than the sum of the values of its adjacent edges*?

Comment: (Consider using a simpler, more focused title - was going to plug *Maximizing the number of nodes in a tree whose …*, noticed I doubt the condition to be unmistakably clear.)

Comment: Here is an idea, you have total 2n-1 values, find the minimum value using sorting. Assign this value to all the edges in the tree, now you will be easily able to assign values to nodes also.